# Excel 14.1.0 (110310) on OSX 10.7.5 doesn't have Full Screen function

Tags: ms-office

I have OSX 10.7.5 on 2009 MacBook with Excel 14.1.0 but I don't have Full Screen function. I Googled and am sure that this version of Excel and OSX should have Full Screen, but I just can't find it. If you can help I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The current version of Excel is 14.3.4.  You may want to update Excel and see if that works.

Comment: Really? I just did auto update and that's the latest version I got. Also I Googled and I got answers from last year claiming this can already be done so I don't know what is wrong. I have a friend with the same OS and excel but he can go full screen. Thank you

Comment: 14.1 is the prerequisite for 14.3.4, so you need to check for updates again to get to the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to 14.3.4 and got the Full Screen feature.